# Add markers to google maps from sqlite database android

Tags: android, sqlite, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-maps-api-2

I'm creating an android app that deals with Points of Interest ! I have also created a local database in which there is a table with all the information about a Poi (name,category,type,longitude,latitude).
I have added several Pois in the database and now I want to add them as markers on google maps .

The problem is that I don't know how to do it exactly. I have search several tutorials on the internet but nothing works as I don't want to add a Marker with constant longitude,latitude , but I want to take them from the database.

Also my db method is using a rawQuery , because I want the longitude and a latitude of the returned Pois to be BETWEEN two values , so I can't find out how to take the columns from it in order to use it later in creating the Poi marker !

```
for(PoiModel poi : PoiHelper.mpoi){
                markerPoi = new MarkerOptions();
                LatLng tag = new LatLng(poi.getY(),poi.getX());
                markerPoi.position(tag)
                .title(poi.getName())
                .snippet(poi.getCategory());
                map.addMarker(markerPoi);
            }
```

Comment: Just in case you are doing this to filter away non visible markers, then there is a neat library for that purpose: https://code.google.com/p/android-maps-extensions/

Comment: I'm doing it because I want to filter the results that get in the ArrayList ! After that I want to add these results to map ! But I can't figure it out yet !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are returning an array I think you shoul do something like this in your map acitivity:

```
private GoogleMap mMap;
private MapView mMapView;   
mMapView = (MapView)findViewById(R.id.map);
mMap = mMapView.getMap();


for( PoiModel mypoi : poi)
{
markerPOI = new MarkerOptions();
markerPOI .position(new LatLng(mypoi .getLatitude(),mypoi .getLongitude()))
        .title(mypoi .getName())
        .snippet(mypoi .getCategory())

mMap.addMarker(markerPOI );
}
```

Comment: How can I do the PoiModel mypoi : poi as poi which is an arralist are in different class ? It says that it can't be resolved ...

Comment: I am assuming *poi* is the arraylist your returning. Maybe you can do this way too: *for (Iterator<PoiModel> iterator = poi.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();)
         {
          PoiModel mypoi  = iterator.next();
         }*

Comment: I finally figure out how to do it , but there is a problem in the for statement... It only runs with the second click of the button in which the OnclickListener I have assigned it ! Any ideas ?

Comment: uploded ! All this is in the Onclick method of OnClickListener

Comment: Make sure the ArrayList of your pois is full at the first time. I think you should use an AsyncTask to read the db and put the makers in the map. Check the [official tutorial](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/05/painless-threading.html).

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the  [LatLng class](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/LatLng.html) and provide it with a lat and lng with doubles you got from the database. Since you already have them just do it like so:

```
LatLng location = new LatLng(latFromDataBase,lngFromDatabase);  
Marker marker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(location).title("some title"));
```

The title part is optional. If you want to change your marker just update its position with a new lat and lng

Comment: The problem is HOW can I provide the LatLng class with the values from Db ?